# Making my module's printk's print to my own logfile

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, printk

I'm doing some Linux module programming. I typically printk little error messages and stuff for debugging - I then exit out of my module and use "dmesg" to see what's up.

That method of debugging is no longer sufficient. I would like to pipe my "printk" text into my own logfile - preferably local, but I understand if that's impossible and I need to put it somewhere like var/log/*.log.

I've looked into editing syslog.conf - but I'm not sure what to do there. I want just my module's printk's in its own files. Is there a simple way to do this that my Google-fu cannot catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to start every `printk's` with the module's unique token:

```
printk("MyModule: ....", ....);
```

1. Use `syslog-ng` (for example) match rule to catch all the module's output
2. Use `tail -f /var/log/messages | grep MyModule to see the live kernel's output

Comment: Ah, I see - but what is that second parameter to printk?